# Eliminating duplicate records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `attribute_value` with the following columns

```
attribute_id | start_date | value | latest_ind | mod_dtime
```

The `latest_ind` column can have a value of either 1 or 0.

I basically want to run an update script on this table which finds all the attributes that have a common `start date` and a `latest_ind` equal to one and set the latest ind to zero EXCEPT in the case where the record is the latest one.

I've managed to put together the following SELECT query but I have no idea how I would go about converting it into an update. Any pointers would be appreciated

```
SELECT av.attribute_id, av.start_date, count(latest_ind), max(mod_dtime)
FROM t_attribute_value av 
where latest_ind = 1 
group by attribute_id, start_date
having count(latest_ind) > 1
```

Comment: Show us sample table data, both before and after the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where an `UPDATE` using a `CTE` comes in handy:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT latest_ind,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY attribute_id, start_date 
                             ORDER BY mod_dtime DESC) AS rn
   FROM attribute_value
   WHERE latest_ind = 1
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET latest_ind = 0
WHERE rn > 1
```

The update operation is propagated to the real table. Hence, in case of a `attribute_id, start_date` partition with a population greater than one, all records but the lastest are updated.

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this

Method 1 : With `CTE`

```
;WITH T AS
(   SELECT attribute_id, start_date, latest_ind,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY av.attribute_id, av.start_date ORDER BY mod_dtime DESC) RN
    FROM t_attribute_value
    where latest_ind = 1
)
UPDATE T
SET latest_ind = 0
WHERE RN > 1
```

Method 2: You don't need a CTE for this

```
UPDATE T
SET T.latest_ind = 0
FROM t_attribute_value T
INNER JOIN
(
        SELECT attribute_id, start_date, latest_ind,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY av.attribute_id, av.start_date ORDER BY mod_dtime DESC) RN
        FROM t_attribute_value
        where latest_ind = 1
) V
   ON T.attribute_id= V.attribute_id AND V.RN > 1
```